# Save audio file with fs.createWriteStream() always downloaded as corrupted file

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore

I have a REST API that that save data from user and insert it to Firestore. From the REST API, user send link to download audio file from some URL and i need to download it to server.

The problem is, if i remove insert query firestore the audio file successfully downloaded. But if i use my query, the file downloaded as corrupted file without any error message in console.

```
const fs = require('fs'),
    db = require('./../config/db'),
    https = require('https');

const download = function(url, dest, cb) {
    let file = fs.createWriteStream(dest);
    https.get(url, function(response) {
        response.pipe(file);
        file.on('finish', function() {
            file.close(cb);
        });
    }).on('error', function(err) {
        fs.unlink(dest);
        if (cb) cb(err.message);
    });
};

// Insert to Firestore
db.collection('results')
.add(data)
.then(response => {
    // Save data as JSON file
    let obj = {
        data: []
    };
    obj.data.push(data);
    let json = JSON.stringify(obj);
    let filename = __dirname + '/../public/json/' + response.id + '_' + dateTime + '.json';
    fs.writeFile(filename, json, 'utf-8', function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.error('Error writing JSON file: ', err);
        }
    });

    // Download recording file
    // var file = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/../public/recording/' + response.id + '_' + dateTime + '.mp3');
    // https.get(insert.recording, function(result) {
    //     result.pipe(file);
    // });

    download(url, __dirname + '/../public/recording/' + response.id + '_' + dateTime + '.mp3', err => {
        console.error(err);
    });
})
.catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
});
```

Is the error because the `download()` is asynchronous?

Comment: Could you show an example where it works to compare with? You're saying there is no error in the console but you believe there is an error, could you elaborate on what is wrong? Your code example doesn't show where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

`download()` is asynchronous function so you need to wrap in using `Promise`